# select sort algorithm (C)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, select, compilation

Im trying to study some algorithm questions and I can't find a way to start my select sort algorithm code. Im using Visual Studio and the code doesn't show any errors through compiling. When I start the code the system just stops for a few seconds and print "press any key to continue...". Im a beginner and I can't see what's wrong. HELP MEEE

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n = 6;

int qwerty(int a[]) {
    int i, j, t;
    for (i=1; i<=n-1; i++){
        for (j=i+1; j<=n; j++){
            if (a[i] > a[j]){
                t = a[j]; 
                a[j] = a[i]; 
                a[i] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int a[6] = { 2, 14, 20, 8, 17, 13 };
    qwerty(a[n]);
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C are zero-based. Before you study algorithms you better get more familiar with the language you are using.

Comment: This is bubble sort

Comment: You need to heed the warnings. Your code does not compile clean.

Comment: Outside of Lua, no major language uses 1 indexed arrays.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar That's not correct. As much as I hate it, so does MATLAB.

Comment: @ThomasJager Fair point.

Comment: There is an error (in MSVC only a warning) about calling the function with `qwerty(a[n])`. It should be `qwerty(a);` and there is another warning about the function not returning a value (even though it isn't used).

Answer (score 2):

In the C language, arrays start indexing at 0, and the last element is at the index *n-1*. So the first thing you should change is the loops to be `for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)` and `for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)`

Also, this is a bubble sort algorithm, not selection sort. Selection sort algorithms can be found anywhere so I'm not going to type it here.